# Adding input value into an array

Tags: arrays, reactjs, input, react-hooks

I am trying to put the user input into my array.

on the initial click of my button its logging out:

input Todo: wash car

Todo List Array:

Questions 1. Why is "todo List Array" not showing "Todo List Array: [ ]" as an empty array?

On the second click of my button its logging:

input Todo:

Todo List Array: wash car (because I typed in wash car in input)

I see that my array is updated on second click. Any reason why its taking two clicks to have my array updated?

my code is below:

```
 const [inputTodo, setInputTodo] = useState("")
    const [todoList, setTodoList] = useState([])
  
    function handleSubmit(){
        console.log(`input Todo: ${inputTodo}`)
        setTodoList(inputTodo)
        setInputTodo("")
        console.log(`Todo List Array: ${todoList}`
    }

    return(
        <div className="addTodo__container">
                    
                <div className="add-Todo__inputWrapper">
                  <input
                    className="add-Todo__input"
                    name="todo"
                    type="text"
                    placeholder="ADD TODO"
                    value={inputTodo}
                    onChange={(e) => setInputTodo([e.target.value])}
                    />
                </div>
             
           <div className="add-Todo__taskButtonContainer">  
            <button className="add-Todo__taskBtn" onClick={handleSubmit}>New Task</button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [useState set method not reflecting change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately)

Comment: T J,
I appreciate it, after reading this article I was able to figure it out by implementing useEffect.

Answer (score 0):

The value of `todoList` is stale inside of the handleSubmit closure. See e.g. [this article for details](https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-hooks-stale-closures/).